# Translating number into currency without jQuery or manipulating the DOM

Tags: meteor

It is said that,

> A good rule of thumb is that if you're using jQuery to manipulate any
>   DOM elements, you're probably doing it wrong.

And:

> Needing access to an element from a helper function indicates that you
>   are trying to use a procedural coding style rather than a
>   template-driven style.

I have a simple number input that I wish to translate into a more comprehensible currency outside it so that the user understands what he is doing. I wanted to do this:

```
<input type="number" class="raw-price">
<p>Price in USD: {{priceInUsd}}</p>
```

And then define a helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  priceInUsd: function() {
    var rawPrice = $('.raw-price').val()
    //perform calculation
    return calculationResult
  }
})
```

First of all, this isn't working (I don't really know why). Second, this goes against the "rules" I posted above. How am I **supposed** to do it? I probably could do this the same way using an event listener instead, but that would still be the wrong approach, I assume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Flash update!

Actually! Here's a better solution: [reactive variables](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity)! If you wish to keep your `rawPrice` in this one template, just install the standard `reactive-var` package:

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

And go at it this way:

Template:

```
<input type="number" class="raw-price">
<p>Price in USD: {{priceInUsd}}</p>
```

onCreated:

```
Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  this.rawPrice = new ReactiveVar;
  this.rawPrice.set(''); // not sure what you want to preset your value to
});
```

Helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  priceInUsd: function() {
    var rawPrice = Template.instance().rawPrice.get()
    //perform calculation
    return calculationResult
  }
})
```

Event:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "change .raw_price": function (evt, template) {
    template.rawPrice.set($(evt.currentTarget).val());
  }
});
```

## Previous (accepted) answer

According to most examples of two-way data binding in meteor I have seen, best case would probably be to use a helper, an event and a Session variable, like so.

Template:

```
<input type="number" class="raw-price">
<p>Price in USD: {{priceInUsd}}</p>
```

Helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  priceInUsd: function() {
    var rawPrice = Session.get('rawPrice');
    //perform calculation
    return calculationResult
  }
})
```

Event:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "change .raw_price": function (evt) {
    Session.set("rawPrice", $(evt.currentTarget).val());
  }
});
```

Sadly, you're using a session variable, but it is still better than using a collection for such a local thing, like I saw in other examples...

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. Feels like I've abused Sessions so much lately that I thought maybe this was an exception to their use-case but I guess not then. :)

Comment: I feel like Meteor could use a nicer way to do this kind of things... it takes only a few lines of code to get the same logic in Angular

Comment: Actually, found a better way to keep your price in the scope. Look it up if you want.

Comment: Oh, cool, I've read about that package but forgot about it. Thanks! Still a bit of code but at least it doesn't use Sessions. :)

Comment: I like your update, @BraveKenny, people use to abuse of Sessions because of this Meteor's feature lack. And actually, it is the way Angular works. Meteor should implement something in order to avoid the previous initialization in onCreated so people starts to forget about using Sessions for absolutely everything.